# Inaccurate hole in object

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make an object that has a hole. I used the boolean modifier with a cylinder selected. But the circle around the object does not look right.

I have the smooth shader turned on and a subdivision of 2 views.

Am I doing something wrong?

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong or a better way of doing it?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Boolean Object]

This is what it looks like with no subdivisions.

But now I cant add a smooth shader or a sub divider to it. Is that just what will have to look like?
[image: No Subdivisions]

This is what I was able to get with no smooth shader.

[image: Done]

Once I do smooth Shader.

[image: With smooth]

Comment: *"used the boolean modifier with a cylinder selected"* the problem is since then. Either retopo the mesh (construct new one with the same forms atop of this one but with cleaner geometry) or undo results by boolean. When subsurfing all tiny long quads, ngons and tris become visible

Comment: I find that the Boolean Modifier works best if it is the only modifier when it is applied. Also, apply Scale to both objects (one at a time) in Object Mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Topology overview:

[image: desc]

You will probably want to go with similar topology for **Smooth Shading** and **Subdivision Surface** modifer.

It's created from simple **Circle**.

1. **Extruded** and **Scaled** outwards.
2. **Extruded** bottom edge.

   *Tip: To streighten **Edge Loop** on the Z axis - press <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd>*
3. Whole shape **extruded**.
4. Bottom part **extruded**.

After this you will need to add **Proximity Loop** to have nice **Bevel** with **Bevel Modifier**.

[image: modifiers]

You can control edge sharpness with **Bevel Width** and number of **Segments**.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: This is a first class answer, explaining how typology is the source of the problem.

Comment: @Neil, Thank you. From my experience topology is a main problem for every beginner who wants to take shortcuts using boleans, ngons, tris and not thinking about proper edge flows. I have more of them here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87176/what-is-the-best-topology-for-this-odd-shape/87218#87218, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75427/bending-a-ping-pong-racket/75432#75432, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80097/turning-incidental-triangles-to-quads/80099#80099, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78903/how-to-properly-fill/78907#78907, and more...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your boolean modifier is before your subsurf modifier. Boolean modifiers create a bunch of nasty triangles or n-gons that do not subdivide well. If you move the boolean to after the subsurf it will have nicer edges, although the shading will be bad probably. If you then enable auto-smooth normals in the object properties panel it should look much better.

Comment: I added updated image with extra comments.

Comment: If you subdivide the cylinder you can make it a lot smoother. As far as I know smooth shading doesn't apply to the mesh generated by the boolean.

Comment: I added more pictures, once without the smooth shading, and then the other with. Is this normal? I tried normalizing and it still didn't do anything.

Comment: Try enabling Auto Smooth in the normals section of the Object properties panel (the tab with the 3 vertex triangle).